# Time evolution operator of a two-level system with a completely general Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, time-evolution, two-level-system

Using the identity ($\sigma_{0}$) and the Pauli operators ($\sigma_{i}$) as a basis, the Hamiltonian of any two-level system can be expressed as follows
$$
H =\alpha \cdot \sigma _{0}+\textbf{r}\cdot\boldsymbol{\sigma}=\alpha \cdot \sigma _{0}+\beta \cdot \sigma _{1}+\gamma \cdot \sigma _{2}+\delta \cdot \sigma _{3}={\begin{pmatrix}\alpha +\delta &\beta -i\gamma \\ \beta +i\gamma &\alpha -\delta \end{pmatrix}}
$$
for some $\alpha,\beta,\delta,\gamma\in\mathbb{C}$. Using the fact that the time evolution operator is given by ${U}(t)=e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}{H}t}$, it is supposedly possible (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-state_quantum_system#Time_dependence) to show that

$$U (t)=e^{-i\alpha t/\hbar }\left(\cos \left({\frac {|\mathbf {r} |}{\hbar }}t\right)\sigma _{0}-i\sin \left({\frac {|\mathbf {r} |}{\hbar }}t\right){\hat {r}}\cdot {\boldsymbol {\sigma }}\right)$$
However, when i try to achieve this result by exponentiating the individual matrix elements I cannot. Is this the incorrect approach? Sorry if this is the wrong place for this!

Comment: A [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) is not defined by exponentiating the individual matrix elements.

Comment: oh right, thanks. how should i obtain the result?

Comment: Try to write down exponential function by definition as infinite power series and then collect the terms